# Show an animated menu in a the parent layout while clicking a button

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a button. 
When I click that button I want show a animated menu in the top of that parent layout that includes an edit text and a button.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `TranslateAnimation`:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html

depending on what kind of animation you have in mind. You start the animation in the `OnClickListener` of your button. You could simply add

```
android:onClick="startAnimation"
```

in your button xml code, and define the

```
public void startAnimation(View v)
```

in your activity.

Maybe this is also helpful:
http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=343

Comment: i need to show a pop up menu(similar to an option menu) in a view when we click a button.

Comment: where exactly are you stuck? handling the button click? doing the animation?

Comment: actully i meant of making a menu visible on a particular option menu click...thats the problem ...